# K Framework - confusion with toy language

Tags: kframework

I am trying to learn kframework, and as an exercise I wanted to attempt to create a high-level language which compiles down to a scripting language for a video game. This high level language does no real execution, just compiles down to the scripting language with rewrite rules.

Example of the original scripting language syntax below

```
variables {
  0: 'message'
}

init {
  SetVariable("message", "Test message");
}

rule("press button") {
  conditions {
    IsButtonPressed(EventPlayer, INTERACT_KEY);
  }
  actions {
    SendMessage(EventPlayer, GetVariable("message"))
  }
}
```

I wanted my high-level language to allow proper variable declarations, so I could write something like this instead, and it would compile down to the script above.

```
init {
  var message = "Test message";
}

rule("press button") {
  conditions {
    IsButtonPressed(EventPlayer, INTERACT_KEY);
  }
  actions {
    SendMessage(EventPlayer, message)
  }
}
```

I know how to make a simple rewrite rule to replace variable declarations `var x = y` with `SetVariable("x", y)`, but how could I also append to the variable declaration block at the top?

I could very well be misunderstanding the capabilities of K, or how I am supposed to be going about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need several cells, one for each major block in your output language. In first phase you populate those cells, then you build the output from their content. I recommend looking into the tutorial, particularly IMP++, which is explained in most detail. https://github.com/kframework/k/tree/master/k-distribution/tutorial/1_k/4_imp%2B%2B That's the best way to understand the capabilities of K. Then you can look at a more complex language like SIMPLE or KOOL.

Comment: @Desik Ahh, thank you! Yes, that approach should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the way you translate one input program into another output program in K is to have an output cell containing the output program as you construct it and to have a sequence of rules that iteratively removes statements and declarations from the input cell and adds them to the output cell in whatever modified form you are expecting. If you have a situation like this where you want to insert something out of order, the way it is typically done is to have a second cell containing a portion of the output program, and the rule that processes the variable declaration modifies two output cells. And then some rule will match later on and combine the outputs together. In this case, that rule would probably apply when the input program has been exhausted.

Here is roughly what that will look like in K:

```
rule <k> var X:Id = E:Expr => . ... </k>
     <output> init { D:Declarations => append(D, SetVariable(Id2String(X), E)) } </output>
     <variables> variables { D:Declarations => append(D, !Y:Int : Id2String(X)) } </variables>
rule <k> . </k>
     <output> P:Program => append(P2, P) </output>
     <variables> P2:Program => . </variables>
```

Note that you would have to write the list append functions yourself. If you really care about performance, you should probably use either the List sort or else append to the front of the cons list and then reverse it afterwards, but I simplified for the purposes of explanation.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!